# JOIN SQL query gives all rows in the result

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL so do not judge strictly.

I have 2 tables:

Cities:

```
id |city           |state ... 
1  |San Francisco  |CA  
2  |Fresno         |CA
3  |Chico          |CA
4  |New York City  |NY
...
```

and

Orders

```
id |city_id   |name        
1  |2         | PlayStation          
2  |3         | Xbox       
3  |3         | Something else       
4  |4         | Something       
...
```

How can I get all the records from the CA state in 1 query?

I tried

```
SELECT c.id, o.id AS order_id, o.name AS order_name
  FROM Cities c
  JOIN Orders o ON o.city_id=c.id
WHERE c.state = 'CA'
```

But it doesn't work, it gives all the records from all states.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Query seems perfect. It must give records you have expected.

Comment: I agree that the query can't possibly return any rows for a state other than 'CA'. Maybe you made a mistake when running it (e.g. highlighted the first three lines when you ran it in your tool, so the where clause got ignored.)

Comment: Your query is ok. Could you please provide a screenshot of where you are running it for further assistance?

Answer (score -1):

Your original query looks OK.  The only thing I can think of is to maybe explicitly specify your `JOIN` as an `INNER JOIN`.

This should also work:

```
SELECT o.city_id, o.id AS order_id, o.name AS order_name
FROM orders o
WHERE city_id IN (SELECT id FROM cities WHERE state = 'CA')
```

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion you would be better off 'linking' these tables rather than performing a 'join'. Example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cities c,
    orders o
WHERE
    c.id = o.city_id
    and c.state = 'CA';
```

Comment: Very bad tip... An _implicit join_ doesn't make any good at all. Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: To be honest I think my above example is much more straightforward for simply bringing two tables together on a small dataset, I don't see the problem with using a link?

Comment: As I said, it's much easier to write correct SQL using explicit joins, i.e. good programming practice. Implicit joins are more error prone.

Comment: I agree that this is very bad advice. I did use comma-separated joins, but that was in the 1980s. They have been made redundant in 1992 for a reason. (And please don't think your "link" is different from a join; it's exactly the same thing, only with an ancient syntax.)